# “launchPackager.command” can’t be opened because (null) is not allowed to open documents in Terminal

Tags: reactjs, react-native, macos, visual-studio-code, terminal

I tried to run a `react-native` project from the Visual Studio Code own terminal with this command `react-native run-android` but I get this error :

[image: error-image]

How can I solve the error `“launchPackager.command” can’t be opened because (null) is not allowed to open documents in Terminal.` with Visual Studio Code in MacMini ?

Comment: Getting the same issue.

Comment: @Mehdi Faraji, were you able to find a solution for this? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @KaviduAlokaKodikara I did post an answer to the question and it worked .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to disable SIP protection until Apple pushes a fix for this problem I followed the steps below :

- Boot into recovery mode by press and hold the power button
- Access Terminal from Utilities
- type csrutil disable
- Restart

Answer (score 0):

While I faced the same issue when running the Android & iOS build specific commands, I found that the Metro server can still be started. It then provides easy options to build the current app for each platform.

What worked for my react-native project with was simply `react-native start`.

This was successful both in the VS Code Terminal and the macOS default Terminal app.